# DateTime format in MySql with timezone in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datetime

Since in MySql there is date and datetime datatype, as far as i know date, i could use 20140822, what about time? could I use '201408221405', representing 2014/08/22 2:05pm ?while my timezone is GMT+8. Please advise the code in VB.Net language, thanks.

Comment: You should not use a string for either data type. Use  the .NET `DateTime` type and use a parameterised query whenever you write this value.

Answer (score 0):

An [atricle](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp) says that you can manipulate the DateTime as

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p')
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%m-%d-%Y')
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %b %y')
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d %b %Y %T:%f')
```

will result in

```
Nov 04 2008 11:45 PM
11-04-2008
04 Nov 08
04 Nov 2008 11:45:34:243
```